# System File Checker cannot complete scanning?

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe, scanning

I am trying to scan for corrupted files in Windows 7 using `sfc/ scannnow` from `cmd`, but the scan stops at `73%` and I get the message:

```
  Windows Resource Protection could not perform the requested operation.
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

### Questions:

1. What could be the problem?
2. How can I solve it?

### Edit:

Here is the result from `sfc /verifyonly`: [sfcdetails.txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d72wq7tf0lmruwi/sfcdetails.txt?dl=0).
Accompanied by the following message:

```
Windows Resource Protection found integrity violations.
```

Comment: What does `sfc /verifyonly` result in? Export your current and the later results with command `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\logs\cbs\cbs.log >sfcdetails.txt ` to dropbox/onedrive/google drive/pastebin and post the link here.

Comment: Also, do you have installation disc of Windows7 with you? Try running a disk check by `chkdsk /r`

Comment: The log file will contain more information.  Furthermore I have only ever had this happen due to a system disk that was starting to fail.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV I'm running `sfc /verifyonly` now. Regarding the installation disc, I'm not sure if I have it. As far as I remember I bought it online and it was with some codes to download a copy or something like that

Comment: Okay, try the check disk command afterwards. If it asks to schedule the scan for running after a restart, allow it.

Comment: @Nikhil_CV link added to the question.

Comment: What about chkdsk?

Comment: @Nikhil_CV just restarted it and ran it, there were a few repairs made

Comment: That explains Ramhound's observation. Is you see errors related to disk again, you should think the chances of failing disk.

Comment: if you use a 64Bit Windows, make sure you run a 64Bit cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What could be the problem?** 
Since disk check (chkdsk) has attempted/fixed some errors, there was some problem/error with your storage media (hard disk) which corrupted the Windows OS related files. Since the files which were corrupted belong to a non important Windows update, its your choice to fix it or ignore it. But to solve System File Checker from failing, we should fix the error brought up by the scan, related to the files.

`sfc /scannow` will attempt to fix the file related corruptions, which got stuck in this case.

`sfc /verifyonly` will check for file corruptions, but will not attempt to fix.

If sfc command fails to fix the corruption, your next option is to extract the file from original media (or do DISM) after eliminating storage media related problems/errors.

**How can I solve it?** 
Here, running the disk check fixed the hard disk related problem and uninstallation or re-installation of the corrupted update will fix the file corruption.
Following is the analysis:

Here is what your log tells:

```
2015-09-21 14:01:53, Info                  CSI    000001bf [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.1.7601.18869, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-09-21 14:01:53, Info                  CSI    000001c1 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.1.7601.18869, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-09-21 14:01:55, Info                  CSI    000001c3 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:24{12}]"utc.app.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.1.7601.18869, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-09-21 14:01:55, Info                  CSI    000001c4 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_250_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.3068708-814_neutral_GDR"
2015-09-21 14:01:55, Info                  CSI    000001c6 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:66{33}]"telemetry.ASM-WindowsDefault.json" of Microsoft-Windows-Unified-Telemetry-Client, Version = 6.1.7601.18869, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral in the store, hash mismatch
2015-09-21 14:01:55, Info                  CSI    000001c7 [SR] This component was referenced by [l:162{81}]"Package_250_for_KB3068708~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.3068708-814_neutral_GDR"
```

This refers to a corruption to a Windows update: [KB3068708](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3068708) (its an update, black listed by some users and writers as one of the '[spy patch](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2981947/microsoft-windows/the-truth-about-windows-7-and-81-spy-patches-kb-3068708-3022345-3075249-and-3080149.html)', simply because it gathers data from your system and sends to MSFT)

> By applying this service, you can add benefits from the latest version of Windows to systems that have not yet been upgraded.

You can see if this update is listed in your ***Control Panel > All Programs and Features > Installed Updates***. If you find it, you should right-click it and select **uninstall**. It will be uninstalled and installed if you choose to install it next time you check for Windows updates.
If not listed in 'Installed updates', try this:

`wusa /uninstall /kb:3068708 /quiet /norestart`